# why the confusion_matrix is different when I execute it again?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mnist

I wonder why the confusion_matrix changes as I execute it in a second time and whether it is avoidable. To be more exact, I got [[53445 597] [958 5000]] for the first time, however, I get [[52556 1486][805 5153]] when I execute it again.

```
# get the data from dataset and split into training-set and test-set
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
# make the data random
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]  
# true for all y_train='2', false for all others
y_train_2 = (y_train == '2')    
y_test_2 = (y_test == '2')

# train the data with a label of T/F depends on whether the data is 2
# I use the random_state as 0, so it will not change, am I right?
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=0)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_2)

# get the confusion_matrix
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train_2, cv=3)
print('confusion_matrix is', confusion_matrix(y_train_2, y_train_pred))
```

Comment: What is it that you execute a second time though? Only the last line? Or everything

Comment: isn't that related to `shuffle_index` changing every time and thus yielding different results?

Comment: I execute everything in a second time

Comment: maybe it is related to shuffle_index,  I will try it again, thank you Crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different data on each run (`shuffle_index`) - so there is no reason for the ML run and resulting confusion matrix to be exactly the same - though results should be close if the algorithm is doing a good job.

To get rid of the randomness either specify indices:

```
shuffle_index = np.arange(60000) #Rather "not_shuffled_index"
```

Or use the same seed:

```
np.random.seed(1) #Or any number
shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000) #Will be the same for a given seed
```